# Is it possible for WCF to transport virtual properties of EF?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

Is it possible for WCF to transport virtual properties?

I have these classes on my project:

```
[DataContract]
class Country
{
    [Key, DataMember] public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string CountryName { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
class Employee
{
    [Key, DataMember] public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public int ResidingInCountryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ResidingInCountryId"), DataMember]
    public virtual Country ResidenceCountry { get; set; }
}
```

I already have `Include` on my WCF:

```
db.Employees.Include("ResidenceCountry").Where(x => x.EmployeeId == 1);
```

But I got this error:

> The underlying connection was closed:
>   The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

That error disappeared if I don't use `virtual`

If it interest anyone, I don't encounter any error on NHibernate when using `virtual` and `Fetch` combo

**[UPDATE: 2011-05-12 3:05 PM]**

I solved my problem by using the solution here: http://www.gavindraper.co.uk/category/entity-framework/

The only difference is I use `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` instead of `this.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;`. I'm using Entity Framework 4.1

Comment: Please add your answer and mark it as accepted so that others will know that this is resolved, thanks.

Comment: Since the link is dead and there isn't much context to the solution...note that the `this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false` should be located in the constructor of your EF DbContext class.

Comment: This has just solved an issue we spent a couple of hours yesterday... to no avail. Setting my DBContext object's ProxyCreationEnabled to false fixed it. I was not not sure if the problem was that I was trying to serialize objects with interfaces or that perhaps the problem was that some of the objects' properties were virtual... turned out that the latter was the problem, and this is the solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just making the solution given above by the asker himself (@GreenLantern) clearer (and perhaps the problem) to anyone that ends in this post...

**Problem: serializing objects with virtual properties**

**Solution: set your DBContext object's Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled to false.**

```
var dbContext = new YourEntityModelObject();
dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: and it must be done on constructor, rather than on OnModelCreating

Comment: Perhaps not the right place to add this, but another issue that might arise in this context is trying to retrieve objects containing objects that implement inheritance - if you do not manually adding the paths with DbSet's include method, the object will be retrieved with null references for them.

Comment: Would you mind extending your answer and add (a) elaborate explanation to why it's needed and (b) show a code sample where you put it the *false* in? (The latter is for the confused and inexperienced to be able to navigate in the source code base. The former is for me - I'm curious why it's needed **but also** what's going to happen if I set the property to false.) I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34463535/losing-connection-when-returning-entity-with-navigational-properties-using-inclu) and it might be the same issue/solution for both.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: Hi Konrad, I honestly will have to research to answer that. My intent here was simply pointing out something that worked for me.

Comment: I took the liberty to add the description for (a) myself. Hope you like it. As or (b), that's OK. If you stumble upon a link or something, you might just add it in the answer.

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I do not think your suggestion is what should be done. You are not supposed to modify auto-generated code. If you wish so, create a class that inherits the auto-generated Context class by Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm bound to agree with you on the principal level. In practice, that might incur a lot of work, though, and I won't be able to persuade my team to do that (they love auto-generated stuff). But, as you say, it's **veeery** wrong to edit such code (because then we need to remember to redo it every time we generate the model). I've been playing around with Code First From Database (yes, there's such a weird option now, hehe) and **that** seems to be something we can use. Would you like to rollback the edition I've made?

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I would remove the editing the auto-generated context class, lest people may jump in doing such things. Thanks however for the inputs. And make an effort to have your site in a language everyone can understand! :-)